# Jqgrid using Coldfusion Json data - Grouping will not work?

Tags: jqgrid, grouping

‘Hi I'm new using jquery and the jqgrid and have hit an issue I cant work out and have searched every where for answers and have found none.'

'I'm developing within the coldfusion environment and my grid loads and populates fine but the grouping that I have enabled is not working and I think it maybe my JSON data format but cant be sure.'

'My JSON format looks like this:'

```
    {"ROWS":[["Account Enquiry","Adding a myki",77.0,105.0,-0.27,385.0,601.0,-0.36],   ["Account Enquiry","Archive cards",0.0,64.0,0.00,451.0,17.0,25.53],["Account Enquiry","Cancelling an account",27.0,52.0,-0.48,164.0,165.0,-0.01],["Account Enquiry","Change of details",305.0,483.0,-0.37,2400.0,2311.0,0.04],["Account Enquiry","Consolidate cards",0.0,84.0,0.00,685.0,45.0,14.22],["Account Enquiry","Obtain Balance",560.0,1272.0,-0.56,6828.0,3604.0,0.89],["Account Enquiry","Removing a myki",16.0,28.0,-0.43,87.0,112.0,-0.22],["Account Enquiry","Retrieve cards",0.0,13.0,0.00,56.0,1.0,55.00],["Account Enquiry","Tax invoice request",11.0,33.0,-0.67,103.0,42.0,1.45],["Account Enquiry","Transaction history",502.0,1035.0,-0.51,5370.0,3334.0,0.61]],"PAGE":1.0,"RECORDS":10,"TOTAL":1.0}
```

'Using the following CFC.’

```
    <cfcomponent displayname="InvoiceMgr"  output="false">
    <cffunction name="getInvoices" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="json">
    <cfset invoices = ArrayNew(1) />
    <cfquery datasource="CS_1″ name="q">
    SELECT  top 10   name, segment, current_month, previous_month, convert(numeric(17,2),m_variance) as m_variance, current_year, previous_year, Convert(numeric(17,2),y_variance) as y_variance
    FROM         dbo.csg_disposition_dashboard_4
    group by name, segment, current_month, previous_month, m_variance, current_year,     previous_year,y_variance
    order by name asc
    </cfquery>
    <cfloop query="q">
    <cfset invoices[currentrow] = [#name#,#segment#,#current_month#, #previous_month#,#m_variance#, #current_year#, #previous_year#,#y_variance#]>
    </cfloop>
    <cfset str = {total=1, page=1, records=#q.recordcount#, rows=invoices}>
    <cfreturn str />
    </cffunction>
    </cfcomponent>
```

‘The Javascript i'm using is:’
        
        
        jqGrid

```
<!–<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />–>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"> 
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/src/grid.base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/src/grid.common.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/src/grid.formedit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/src/grid.inlinedit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/src/grid.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/src/jquery.fmatter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/src/grid.grouping.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/src/grid.treegrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/src/grid.jqueryui.js"></script>

    <!–<script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>–>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'contacts1.cfc?method=getInvoices',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames:['Source','Segment','August','July','Variance','2011','2010','Variance'],
    colModel :[
    {name:'name',index:'name', width:250, editable:true},
    {name:'segment',index:'segment', width:200},
    {name:'current_month',index:'current_month',    width:100,align:"center",sorttype:"int",summaryType:'sum'},
    {name:'previous_month',index:'previous_month', width:100,align:"center",sorttype:"int",summaryType:'sum'},
    {name:'m_variance',index:'m_variance', width:80,align:"center",sorttype:"int",summaryType:'avg'},
    {name:'current_year',index:'current_year', width:100,align:"center",sorttype:"int",summaryType:'sum'},
    {name:'previous_year',index:'previous_year', width:100,align:"center",sorttype:"int",summaryType:'sum'},
    {name:'y_variance',index:'y_variance', width:80,align:"center",sortable:false,summaryType:'avg'}],
    pager: $('#pager'),
    rowList:[100,300,600,1000],
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    sortname: "name",
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    jsonReader: {
    root: "ROWS",
    page: "PAGE",
    total: "TOTAL",
    cell: "",
    id: "id",
    caption: "Disposition Codes",
    grouping:true,
    groupingView : {
           groupField : ['name'],
        groupDataSorted : true
            }

    }}
    );
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="list" class="scroll"> <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-    align:center;"> </body>
    </html>
```

‘I really would like some help on this as I'm at the end of sanity,  head hitting desk.

Looking forward to someone knowing the answer.

Regards
Mayson’

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your jQGrid version is 3.8+, as it will not work for previous version. The way you are defining your jqgrid script files, it seems like you are using older version